# flex scatterplot custom renderer

Tags: apache-flex, plot, renderer, scatter

I have a scatter plot with 10 points,
some points are above and below some thresh hold.

I need to show different color for those

- above thresh hold
- below thresh hold
- within thresh hold

Effectively, can the 10 points be colored a different color?

Is it possible to do this with some renderer ?
I am looking for a renderer since , the logic may become more complex than thresh hold.

The other way is to create and add separate series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this helpful link, adding it here to help somebody else having similar requirement. 
I was searching by some other key words and it usually got me to diamond and other renderer for scatter plot. hope to configure this for the scatter plot.

[adobe link to solution](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_a_programmatic_renderer_in_your_ColumnChart-2021.html)